pyside6 rendering a QPdfView to a QPrintPreviewDialog
so first  ill start off and say im fairly new to QT or pyside6 in general.
this is my class
class Viewer(QPdfView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget | None = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setPageMode(QPdfView.PageMode.MultiPage)
        self.setVisible(False)

    def print_(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self.parent())
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.draw)
        dialog.exec()

    def draw(self, printer: QPrinter):
        painter = QPainter(printer)
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing | QPainter.RenderHint.TextAntialiasing |
            QPainter.RenderHint.SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter.RenderHint.LosslessImageRendering,
            True
        )
        document = self.document()
        options = QPdfDocumentRenderOptions()
        options.setRenderFlags(
            QPdfDocumentRenderOptions.RenderFlag.ImageAliased |
            QPdfDocumentRenderOptions.RenderFlag.TextAliased |
            QPdfDocumentRenderOptions.RenderFlag.ForceHalftone
        )

        print_range = printer.pageRanges()
        rng = print_range.toString().split("-")
        rng = [i.strip() for i in rng if i.strip().isdigit()]
        if len(rng) == 2:
            range_ = range(int(rng[0]) - 1, int(rng[1]))
        elif len(rng) == 1:
            range_ = tuple([int(rng[0]) - 1])
        else:
            range_ = range(document.pageCount())
        if max(range_) > document.pageCount():
            range_ = range(document.pageCount())
        layout = printer.pageLayout()
        if layout.orientation() == QPageLayout.Orientation.Landscape:
            printer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout.Orientation.Landscape)
        if layout.pageSize().isValid():
            printer.setPageSize(layout.pageSize())
        for i in range_:
            if i > 0:
                printer.newPage()
            printer.setPageMargins(layout.margins())
            target_rect = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
            image_size = QSize(int(target_rect.width()), int(target_rect.height()))
            image = document.render(i, image_size, options)
            if not image.isNull():
                painter.drawImage(target_rect, image)
        painter.end()

right now the current solution is working very slow as i render each page to an image and then render it to the printer, which takes forever, i thought maybe i can somehow render the QPdfView it self to the printer but couldnt figure out how
any help will be greatly appricated!
wrote the self.draw method, it works, but very slow and inefficent

You can't render the content of the QPdfView into the QPrinter directly. The slowness is due to the QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution. Just use the QPrinter.PrinterMode.ScreenResolution.

thank you for your help!
if i do use ScreenResolution the document loses quality which i'd prefer to avoid
i can render the QPdfView to the printer, it's just that its output is only whats currently visible on the screen (if for example i have scroll down area, it will only show whats currently the widget is displaying) and the output is extreamly tiny, which makes me belive theres a way to render it directly, but i dont know how / didnt find a solution online

I'm actually trying to answer your question, but it will take some time, as using the print preview implies some important aspects you're underestimating; most importantly, the fact that the dialog provides a "print" button that will eventually use the generated preview images. In the meantime, some important notes: 1. your pageRanges.toString() usage is unreliable and unacceptable, you should construct the proper page range recursively; 2. setting the printer size/orientation based on its layout is completely pointless, since printer.pageLayout() is already based on the printer setting;


PDF documents consider the whole paper size, not the "page" (excluding margins), so you should not use pageRect(), otherwise the printing will be shifted by the paper margins; 4. the render() function of QPdfDocument always renders a QImage, setting the QPainter Antialiasing and TextAntialiasing (which is set by default) is completely useless; also, the True argument is implied; 5. newPage() should always be called if the page is not the last, not if the page is not the first (if the page range starts with the second page, you'll get an empty page).


Thank you for the tips! I have made changes to the range, and removed the unnecessary render hints, and fixed the newpage() part. Sadly printing is still slow so I'm thinking about writing my own print preview dialog and render in a different Thread

@Clueless I've been doing further research, as I believe that the behavior of QPrintPreview dialog and widgets is not acceptable under some circumstances, with this one specifically problematic due to the fact that it uses rendering to images: 1. the pdf renderer requires time to render pages and scale them; 2. they occupy a lot of memory if the document has many pages. Right now I've scaled it down to two possibilities, both having pros and cons: either programmatically get the cache using a queue and request an updatePreview() every time a new page has been rendered, or use the »

@Clueless » internal QGraphicsView by creating custom QGraphicsItems embedded in the "virtual pages" that eventually request the page to the renderer whenever they are actually painted. The first approach is slightly simpler, but can also cause some lagging while scrolling (during rendering), while the second seems much faster, but has some indirect issues like incorrect geometry adjustments or proper current page updates (sometimes it returns 0). I'll do some more research in the next days and eventually answer accordingly. (please remember to use @username, I saw your reply just by chance)

Note: the OP is asking a controversial question, in the sense that its solutions may require lots of efforts to be answered, despite the relatively simple and specific question.
I don't generally answer such posts, but I also agree that PDF printing in Qt (in the sense of printing a PDF document to a printer), as relatively uncommon as it may be, lacks proper support, possibly due to its very nature. There are some slightly related questions even here on SO, so the purpose of this answer is to also indirectly address them too.
Printing performance: memory and processing
Printing is not immediate as one would think.
Generally, it finally happens through many layers, also considering the abstraction the OS may provide and those the underlying printing system may use.
Your main issue, as you've already found out, is that the print preview dialog (more specifically, the underlying QPrintPreviewWidget) is synchronous: it won't return control to the event loop until it's finished. Setting a small resolution for the printer will have little benefits for large PDF documents (especially if they use images)
This is obviously a huge bottleneck, especially considering that the PDF renderer actually outputs full sized images, even though they're shown as "small thumbnails": a common page may require tens of megaBytes of memory at full printer resolution even for blank pages, which affects performance for memory allocation alone to begin with.
Since the QtPdf API uses images for rendering, this means that each page has to be fully processed as an image at its full final resolution, after considering its contents.
Using QtPdf features with QPrinter
Luckily, the QtPdf module has an intermediate QPdfPageRenderer class, that provides multithreading features through its setRenderMode(). This is what QPdfView actually uses on its own, but it's not enabled by default.
Unfortunately, there's a catch. QPrintPreviewWidget (and, directly, QPrintPreviewDialog) is based on the premise that whenever its paintRequested signal is emitted, all printing has to be finalized.
The QPagedPaintDevice API (on which QPrinter is based) is always sequential, meaning that you cannot "go back" to print a previous page once newPage() has been called; it makes sense, if you think about it: once a page has been printed, the printer cannot "go back" and change its contents.
The result of the above is that the print preview thumbnails will only be shown as soon as the painter created for that printer has been finalized; in other words, when the slot connected to paintRequested() finally returns control to the main event loop.
One possible solution is to use the aforementioned multithreading mode of the QPdfPageRenderer and queue new pages as soon as they're shown. This may work fine in C++, but, as we all know, Python doesn't allow that due to the GIL. Also, this won't solve the memory issue: if you want previews that can be zoomed in while keeping good rendering quality, it's easy to end up with some gigabytes of memory used for a simple preview.
Using multiprocessing may be a solution, but only under specific circumstances: specifically, we need a detached PDF file for the separate process. This may not always be possible, as the current QtPDF module doesn't provide ways of "backward" access to the source PDF document, nor direct writing capabilities. If the PDF is created dynamically (or there is no more access to the file object on which it's based), this is just impossible if not by using external libraries.
The only solution I can think of, in that case, would be to write a temporary file at extremely high resolution, based on the source PDF. This is obviously not efficient, especially for large files.
Using the threading approach may be better, but it doesn't come without issues, at least using Python bindings.
Most importantly, it requires calling the preview widget's updatePreview() function whenever a new rendering is finalized, which can cause temporary and annoying freeze of the UI when scrolling a large document. And we still have the issue of memory management, meaning that every time the view is resized/scrolled or the preview zoom factor is changed, we need to generate new previews to avoid large images using unnecessary memory for the process.
A possible solution hack
QPrintPreviewWidget is actually based on the Graphics View framework. Once the printing triggered by paintRequested is finalized, it creates custom QGraphicsItems instances in its scene, one for each page. This is done efficiently using QPicture: Qt takes the QPainter commands used on the QPrinter and creates small "painting macros" that can be replayed for each item.
The trick is to create empty pages for the whole document page range, and therefore create custom child items for each of them. Those custom items will be actually responsible of showing the real contents of each page, interacting with a main underlying QPdfPageRenderer and a temporary cache for better performance and memory usage.
The main benefit of this approach is that control will return almost immediately to the main loop, showing the "empty" pages immediately. The custom items will therefore emit a signal to request their contents when their paint() is called, if their cached image is not available yet.
The drawback is that this approach is based on many undocumented aspects, so not only it requires some specific work arounds, but it's also not fully reliable and may even hugely fail in future Qt releases.
The concept is mainly based on a custom QGraphicsObject subclass (as opposed as the basic QGraphicsItem, so that it can provide signals); its instances will always be created as children of each private PageItem item in the QGraphicsScene of the QPrintPreviewWidget's graphics view.
That subclass will need some important arguments: the page it refers to, a pointer to the "global" page cache, it's actual size, and the parent item created by the internal QGraphicsScene.
Here is an overview of the whole process:

the paintRequested signal of QPrintPreviewDialog is emitted;
in the connected function, new, blank pages are created based on the printer page ranges, completing the process almost instantly;
before returning, 0-based single shot QTimer is started to run a separate function; using a QTimer is required in order to be triggered right after the new "PageItem" graphics items are internally created;
that function creates instances of the above subclass as children of the existing "PageItem" in the scene, with pointers to a "page cache" of their specific page, containing possible renderings of the page at different resolutions;
the paint() override of those custom items will check the given "page cache":

if the page exists at the given scale (the QTransform used by the painter argument), it will draw its contents;
if the page exists at a different scale, it will draw that instead and request the proper scale by emitting a related signal;
if no thumbnail exist for that page, it draws a placeholder content and then request the correct preview with the above signal;


the signal of the custom item is connected to a function that eventually asks to the QPdfPageRender (properly set to use multi threading) for the scaled thumbnail, using requestPage();
as soon as a page is rendered, the pageRendered signal is emitted, and the function connected to it asks to the related custom item for that page to schedule an update in order to show it;

Finally, a persistent timer checks the current memory usage and eventually removes unnecessary thumbnails: if other thumbnails are requested in the meantime, check the memory usage and eventually clear some of its contents to avoid memory and performance issues.
Now, as said, all this requires some further precaution. Most importantly, in order to optimize rendering, memory usage and unnecessary requests, we need to ensure that each custom item is always and only drawn when required.
QPrintPreviewWidget and its related dialog do that on their own, using private functions and slots, but our implementation complicates things.
This is still doable from Python bindings, though; we just need to know what signals are emitted, to what slots they're connected and eventually "rewire" all that by giving precedence to some calls. This is important as some aspects of the default behavior just rely on its simplicity: for instance, the currentPage() of QPrintPreviewWidget is only updated when the vertical scroll bar of the graphics view is moved, and considers all items in the scene: since we're adding other items, the result may be unexpected (for instance, the page field in the dialog may show negative or unexpectedly large numbers).
The following code should consider all aspects mentioned above, but be also aware that:

as said, this may not work in future Qt releases (at the time of writing, it seems to work for the 6.6 Qt branch, both with PySide and PyQt);
the paintRequested signal is also used for actual printing when clicking the "Print" button on the print dialog toolbar, in the code I have just disconnected the "preview slot" and connected to a "print" one for demonstration purposes; I'll leave to you to properly print to a physical printer using the correct resolution, page order, etc.;
since the QtPDF rendering is image based, this means that extremely high resolution printers or further PDF-output will eventually print blurred or aliased contents;

def bestScale(value):
    '''
        Sanitize the scale to a reasonable value:
        - if the scale is smaller than half (0.5) always return 0.5;
        - if the scale is greater than 10 always return 8: the scaling is 
          too extreme and it does not make a lot of sense to capture such a 
          huge preview, considering the memory cost;
        - if the scale is equal or greater than 2 always return a factor
          equal to 2 + 3/4 of the difference from 2, in order to provide
          reasonable memory and CPU performance with acceptable image output;
        - otherwise, return the same value, rounded to the fifth decimal
          (arbitrary) to avoid float errors;
    '''
    if value <= .5:
        return .5
    elif value > 10:
        # do we really need a zoom higher than 800%?
        return 8
    elif value > 2:
        return round(2 + (value - 2) * .75, 5)
    return round(value, 5)


class PagePreviewItem(QGraphicsObject):
    lastScale = -1
    previewRequested = pyqtSignal(int, float)
    def __init__(self, page, cache, brect, font, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.page = page
        self.pageStr = str(page + 1)
        self.cache = cache
        self._boundingRect = brect
        self.font = font

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect

    def drawAtScale(self, qp, scale):
        if not scale in self.cache:
            # try to find the closest available cache image for this scale
            scale = sorted(self.cache, key=lambda s: abs(scale - s))[0]
            if scale < 1.5:
                qp.setRenderHint(qp.RenderHint.SmoothPixmapTransform)
            res = False
        else:
            if scale >= 5:
                qp.setRenderHint(qp.RenderHint.SmoothPixmapTransform)
            res = True

        qp.drawImage(self._boundingRect, self.cache[scale])
        return res

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget=None):
        scale = bestScale(qp.transform().m11())
        if self.cache and self.drawAtScale(qp, scale):
            return

        if self.lastScale != scale:
            self.lastScale = scale
            self.previewRequested.emit(self.page, scale)

        if not self.cache:
            qp.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.gray)
            qp.setFont(self.font)
            qp.drawText(
                self._boundingRect, 
                Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, 
                self.pageStr
            )


class PdfPrintPreviewDialog(QPrintPreviewDialog):
    _viewScale = -1
    def __init__(self, doc, printer=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(printer, parent)
        self.doc = doc
        self.pageFormats = []
        allRotations = set()

        # the following can take some time for large PDF documents that have
        # not been previously rendered, if they have lots of pages and/or
        # are raster based (images instead of vector contents)
        for page in range(doc.pageCount()):
            size = doc.pagePointSize(page)
            pageSize = QPageSize(size, QPageSize.Unit.Point)
            # the rotation is just an assumption, and may not work with some
            # page sizes (eg. Ledger) having widths larger than heights
            rotate = False
            if pageSize.id() == QPageSize.PageSizeId.Custom:
                altPageSize = QPageSize(size.transposed(), QPageSize.Unit.Point)
                if altPageSize.id() != QPageSize.PageSizeId.Custom:
                    size.transpose()
                    rotate = True
                elif size.width() > size.height():
                    rotate = True
            allRotations.add(rotate)
            self.pageFormats.append((size, rotate))

        self.pageCache = {}
        self.pageQueue = OrderedDict()
        self.previewItems = {}
        self.requests = {}

        self.itemTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True, 
            interval=0, timeout=self._createChildItems)
        self.queueTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True, 
            interval=10, timeout=self._handleNextRequest)
        self.memoryTimer = QTimer(self, 
            interval=2000, timeout=self._memoryCheck)

        self.renderer = QPdfPageRenderer(self)
        self.renderer.setDocument(doc)
        self.renderer.setRenderMode(self.renderer.RenderMode.MultiThreaded)

        self.previewWidget = self.findChild(QPrintPreviewWidget)
        self.previewWidget.setAllPagesViewMode()
        self.view = self.previewWidget.findChild(QGraphicsView)
        self.view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        self.paintRequested.connect(self.updatePreview)
        self.renderer.pageRendered.connect(self._pageRendered)

        vb = self.view.verticalScrollBar()
        vb.valueChanged.disconnect()
        vb.valueChanged.connect(self.view._q_vslide)
        vb.valueChanged.connect(self._q_updateCurrentPage)
        self.view.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self._forceUpdate)

        prntStr = QApplication.translate('QPrintPreviewDialog', 'Print')
        landscapeStr = QApplication.translate(
            'QPrintPreviewDialog', 'Landscape')

        for action in self.findChildren(QAction):
            if action.text() == prntStr:
                # disconnect and reconnect in the proper order
                action.triggered.disconnect()
                action.triggered.connect(self._prePrint)
                action.triggered.connect(self._q_print)
                action.triggered.connect(self._postPrint)
            elif action.text() == landscapeStr:
                # if all *assumed* rotations are the same and they seem
                # to use a landscape format, trigger the related action
                if len(allRotations) == 1 and tuple(allRotations)[0]:
                    printOrient = self.printer().pageLayout().orientation()
                    if printOrient == QPageLayout.Orientation.Portrait:
                        action.trigger()

        # fit the first page in view
        singleModeAction = self.findChild(QAction, 'singleModeAction')
        QTimer.singleShot(0, singleModeAction.trigger)

        self.memoryTimer.start()

    def _memoryCheck(self):
        if not self.pageCache:
            return

        visiblePages = []
        for item in self.view.items(self.view.viewport().rect()):
            if isinstance(item, PagePreviewItem):
                visiblePages.append(item.page)

        currentScale = bestScale(self.previewWidget.zoomFactor())
        # the default zoom in/out factor is 1.1, let's keep images that are
        # within that range and discard the rest, unless they're small enough.
        minScale = currentScale / 1.2
        maxScale = currentScale * 1.2
        for page, scaleCache in self.pageCache.items():
            for cachedScale in tuple(scaleCache):
                if cachedScale <= .75:
                    continue
                elif (
                    page not in visiblePages 
                    or not minScale < cachedScale < maxScale
                ):
                    del scaleCache[cachedScale]

    def _q_updateCurrentPage(self):
        # call the default connected slot only after hiding our custom items,
        # to ensure that the default implementation works as expected
        items = self.previewItems.values()
        if not items or len(items) == len(self.view.items()):
            self.previewWidget._q_updateCurrentPage()
            return
        for i in items:
            i.hide()
        self.previewWidget._q_updateCurrentPage()
        self._forceUpdate()
        for i in items:
            i.show()

    def _createChildItems(self):
        items = self.view.items()
        if hasattr(items[0], 'preview') or isinstance(items[0], PagePreviewItem):
            return
        self.previewItems.clear()
        items.sort(key=lambda i: [i.y(), i.y()])

        paperRect = self.printer().pageLayout().fullRectPixels(
            self.printer().resolution())

        # get a proper font that fits all page numbers
        font = self.font()
        fontSize = paperRect.height()
        font.setPixelSize(int(fontSize))
        fm = QFontMetrics(font)
        width = fm.boundingRect(' {} '.format(self.lastPage)).width()
        if width > paperRect.width():
            font.setPixelSize(int(fontSize * paperRect.width() / width))

        paperBoundingRect = QRectF(paperRect)
        for item, page in zip(items, self.pageRange):
            if page in self.pageCache:
                pageCache = self.pageCache[page]
            else:
                pageCache = self.pageCache[page] = {}
            previewItem = PagePreviewItem(
                page, pageCache, paperBoundingRect, font, item)
            previewItem.previewRequested.connect(self._queueRequest)
            self.previewItems[page] = previewItem

    def _forceUpdate(self):
        previewItems = self.previewItems.values()
        viewRect = self.view.viewport().rect()
        for item in self.view.items(viewRect):
            if item in previewItems:
                item.lastScale = -1
                item.parentItem().update()

    def _startQueueTimer(self):
        # decide how soon the next request is handled
        visibleCount = len(self.view.items(self.view.viewport().rect()))
        if visibleCount >= 8:
            timeout = 50
        elif visibleCount > 4:
            timeout = 100
        elif visibleCount > 2:
            timeout = 200
        else:
            timeout = 500
        if (
            not self.queueTimer.isActive()
            or self.queueTimer.remainingTime() > timeout
        ):
            self.queueTimer.start(timeout)

    def _handleNextRequest(self, force=False):
        if not self.pageQueue:
            return

        page, reqScale = self.pageQueue.popitem(False)
        scale = bestScale(self.previewWidget.zoomFactor())
        if reqScale != scale and not force:
            return

        thumbSize = (self.paperSize * scale).toSize()

        # rotation/orientation is just an assumption!
        printOrient = self.printer().pageLayout().orientation()
        printRotate = printOrient != QPageLayout.Orientation.Portrait
        pageSize, rotate = self.pageFormats[page]
        opt = QPdfDocumentRenderOptions()
        if printRotate != rotate:
            if rotate:
                opt.setRotation(opt.Rotation.Clockwise270)
            else:
                opt.setRotation(opt.Rotation.Clockwise90)
        elif rotate:
            pageSize = pageSize.transposed()

        requestId = self.renderer.requestPage(page, thumbSize, opt)
        self.requests[requestId] = scale

        if self.pageQueue:
            self._startQueueTimer()

        memSize = thumbSize.width() * thumbSize.height() * 4
        if memSize * len(self.pageQueue) > 125000000:
            # try to clear memory if there are too many requests
            self._memoryCheck()

    def _pageRendered(self, page, size, image, options, requestId):
        if not requestId in self.requests:
            # ignore previously queued requests
            return

        approxFactor = self.requests.pop(requestId)
        if page in self.pageCache:
            self.pageCache[page][approxFactor] = image
        else:
            self.pageCache[page] = {approxFactor: image}
        if not page in self.previewItems:
            # unlikely...
            self._createChildItems()
        item = self.previewItems[page]
        item.lastScale = -1
        item.update()

    def _queueRequest(self, page, scale):
        if page in self.pageQueue:
            self.pageQueue.move_to_end(page, False)
        self.pageQueue[page] = scale
        if (
            not self.queueTimer.isActive() 
            and not page in self.pageCache
            or not self.pageCache[page]
        ):
            self._handleNextRequest(True)
        else:
            self._startQueueTimer()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.Paint and self.previewItems:
            scale = self.view.transform().m11()
            if self._viewScale != scale:
                self._viewScale = scale
                self._forceUpdate()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def _prePrint(self):
        self.queueTimer.stop()
        self.paintRequested.disconnect(self.updatePreview)
        self.paintRequested.connect(self.printRequested)

    def _postPrint(self):
        self.paintRequested.disconnect(self.printRequested)
        self.paintRequested.connect(self.updatePreview)
        if self.pageQueue:
            self._startQueueTimer()

    def printRequested(self, printer):
        # actual printing: this should use the printer page ranges, 
        # resolution, page order, etc...
        pass

    def updatePreview(self, printer):
        self.queueTimer.stop()
        self.pageQueue.clear()
        self.requests.clear()

        self.pageCount = self.doc.pageCount()

        if not self.pageCount:
            if self.itemTimer.isActive():
                self.itemTimer.stop()
            return

        self.pageRange = range(self.pageCount)
        self.lastPage = self.pageRange[-1]

        self.paperSize = printer.paperRect(QPrinter.Unit.DevicePixel).size()

        qp = QPainter(printer)
        for i in self.pageRange[:-1]:
            printer.newPage()
        qp.end()

        self.itemTimer.start()

        if not self.pageCache:
            # process the first page immediately
            self.pageQueue[0] = .5
            self._handleNextRequest(True)

Some further notes:

while researching about this subject, I found out that the QPrintPreviewWidget (and its related dialog) have been left on their own for quite some time, with many inconsistencies and bugs; for instance, at least on Linux, the QPrintDialog opened when clicking the "Print" button on the dialog may change the QPrinter reference if another printer is selected and the dialog is cancelled; there are other issues too, some of which related to Linux only; be advised, as the printer status may change without ensuring that paintRequested is triggered again with the new printer or its settings (except for the page orientation);
I've only tested the above on Linux, meaning that some aspects are based on the underlying CUPS system, which causes some inconsistencies in QPrinter on Windows and macOS (specifically, printer resolutions);
preview and memory management are based on assumptions; a more accurate implementation should carefully check the underlying printing system, resolution, screen DPI and, possibly, available system memory;
as said, many aspects are based on undocumented features, things may change in future Qt versions;
all the above is a huge collection of workarounds that try to overcome QPrintPreviewDialog and QPrintPreviewWidget issues and missing features; you should actually consider if it's worth it, and it might not: at some point, it doesn't make sense anymore to try to fix something that doesn't work; those classes are intended as generic interfaces, if you need something more specific and "fixing" an existing implementation is so overwhelming, it may be more reasonable to create it on your own starting from scratch;

